# What happens to $\frac{\tan\left(\sin x\right)-\sin\left(\tan x\right)}{x^4}$ near $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

When I was drawing some interesting graph of functions, I found a strange phenomenon. A function $f(x)=\tan(\sin x)-\sin(\tan x)$ is well defined on $\mathbb{R}-\left\{\left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)\pi:n\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$, and it has oscillation near $x=\left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)\pi$ by the $\sin(\tan x)$ term. It doesn't oscillate near $0$.

And since
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\tan(\sin x)-\sin(\tan x)}{x^4}=0$$
by taylor expansion, a function defined by
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{\tan(\sin x)-\sin(\tan x)}{x^4}\quad&\mathrm{if}\quad x\neq 0,\,  \left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)\pi\\0&\mathrm{if}\quad x=0\end{cases}$$

is continuous in it's domain. I guessed that $g$ may oscillate at $x=\left(\frac{1}{2}+n\right)\pi$ and not at $x=0$. However, when I plot the graph of $g$ using Desmos or GeoGebra, there's a strange oscillation near $x=0$. Here is the graph.

[image: graph of the function]

The similar phenomenon occurs for $x^5$, $x^6$ instead of $x^4$, and I can't understand why it occurs. I tried to investigate sign of $g'$ and get a supremum of $g$ near $0$, but both didn't give me useful information because of complicated calculation. Why this strange oscillation occurs near $0$? Or it's just a numerical error? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: That must be an issue with the softwares since $$g(x) = \frac{1}{{30}}x^3  + \frac{{29}}{{756}}x^5  +  \cdots $$ near $x=0$. I used another software to plot $g(x)$ and it looks perfectly fine for $|x|<\frac{1}{2}$ say.

Comment: Which software could plot this well? I want to see the graph. Both Desmos and GeoGebra doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is underflow.  You are taking the difference between two functions and dividing by $x^4\approx 10^{-16}$.  If either of your first numbers has been rounded off by $10^{-20}$, that will cause the error around $0.0001$ that you saw.
Floating point numbers almost always have tiny errors because they are approximated by nearby numbers whose denominator can only be a power of $2$.  These errors don't usually matter, down in the 20th decimal place.  You have managed to make the errors significant.

Answer (score 3):

What software/hardware are you using? The problem is when you are doing a "small/small" type of computation on computers, there tend to be a lot of error, as the floating point arithmetic is never precise. In fact, a large part of numerical analysis is about how to handle this problem.

If you use a math software that's more symbolic in nature, you'll be able to see a smooth curve.

E.g., if you type "plot((tan(sin(x))-sin(tan(x)))/(x^4), (x,-1,1))" to https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ and hit evaluate, you'll see [image: Plot]

I guess Mathematica will do the same, but I don't have a license for it now.

But if you try to zoom in, try "plot((tan(sin(x))-sin(tan(x)))/(x^4), (x,-0.01,0.01))", you'll see a similar pattern (which really shows the limit of numerical computation):

[image: Plot2]

And [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%28Tan%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5D-Sin%5BTan%5Bx%5D%5D%29%2Fx%5E4%2C%7Bx%2C-0.01%2C0.01%7D%5D) isn't doing any better.